# Could S[OUF] get a tag cloud similar to the one on The Climate Deal StackExchange?

Tags: feature-request, tags

So I really like the tag cloud on Climate Deal. Is there anyway we could get something similar to this on StackOverflow? I don't necessarily mean that we should replace the interesting/ignored tags with this but something like this on the front page would be nice.

[image]

Comment: First there was Stack Overflow **(O).** Then there was Server Fault **(F)**. Then came Super User **(U).** In order they would be OFU.

Comment: @random: Sorry but I just don't like that order. OUF is easier to pronounce then OFU plus I feel bad after saying it your way. ;-)

Comment: Oh, Eff Yoo!  Yeah, might not be appropriate depending on the audience.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Call me crazy, but how would you actually ***use*** that? How would it help you? In most cases you want a **specific** piece of information - you don't come to a tech site to find out what is "trending".

For me, **search** is the important navigation device for people looking for information, and in most cases that means google.

Am I just too old-school?

Comment: Dear Mr. Gravell, Notice that I have installed a tag cloud in your tag cloud so that you may trend while you trend.  Dog.

Answer (score 1):

I would like it on a separate page.  I believe there is some value in seeing what programmers are asking about.  I wouldn't want it cluttering up the front page, though.

Answer (score 0):

I admit it looks quite cool, but I've got absolutely no doubt at all that it would never actually be used (in fact I'd quite like to see it happen just to see the logs of how few people used it).

Besides, it would probably look far less interesting for StackOverflow - just a big C# in the middle.

Also, you could make it yourself using the creative commons data dump.

**UPDATE:** To satisfy my own curiosity I created a quick tag cloud using the first 7-8 pages of tags on StackOverflow using [this](http://phasetwo.org/post/a-better-tag-cloud.html) nifty looking tag cloud (looks cool, but its even less useful than the above tag cloud as it has no text until you hover over it)

Anyway its [here](http://www.sticksofrage.co.uk/tagcloud/stackoverflow.html)

Comment: Or even just scrapping the tag list page.

Answer (score -1):

If it weren't for closed posts being included in the count for each tag (see https://stackoverflow.com/tags), anyone could create one and post it here for us all to go "ooh! ahh!" over (including duplicates and other closed posts is a bit misleading, IMHO).

But yeah, tag clouds are nifty for visualizing data.